# ODBC Connection not established when Misrosoft Office not installed

Tags: c#, csv

I have created a console application in VS 2008 which will read from a .csv file and perform some action. The application is running fine in my local system but when I try to run the same in one of the server (windows server 2008 R2) it is unable to establish connection through odbc connection and through error. Microsoft Office is not installed in my server. I have created a set up file and added Office Primary Interop Assembly as prerequisite but no use.Can anyone help me with solution to this?

Connection string for the ODBC Connection is below -

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

string strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + this.dirCSV.Trim() + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False";
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());
conn.Open();
```